# Understand a warning from an OpenCV window object

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the OpenCV Python library as GUI for some experimts.

The program I wrote works perfectly. I do not post it all here because 
cv2.namedWindow(PLOT_EYMOL_CONTROLLER)It is very large and takes different files.

The problem is, I read a warning on the terminal, and I would like to know what is me actually warning on. The message is

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

It refers to a CV window which I defined like this

```
cv2.namedWindow('Controller')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the line

```
cv2.namedWindow('Controller')
```

It seems the warning comes when you create an object and do not use it for a long time. The library routines, automatically creates the object in case you refer to it.